# 8 - Views: list pages that are child menu items to the current node

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I have three nodes:

- Node A
- Node B
- Node C

In the main menu, these nodes are organized with Node B and C as children of Node A's menu item, like so:

- Node A

  - Node B
  - Node C

When Node A is viewed, I would like to display/list Node B and C in a block under Node A's content.

I would like to do this without using the Book module. I would also like to do this without adding an extra step to the user (i.e. using entity reference on Node A).

Is there a way to do this views? i.e. to create a relationship to the menu structure?

Here's a drawing of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate answering my own question here, but just to save the effort anyone might be going through, here is a module that worked for me:

[Views Menu Node Children Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_menu_children_filter)

Using this module I was able to pass the node ID of the current node and filter the node's children in reference to the menu structure. Works perfectly on 8.4.

Comment: Couldn’t Menu Block solve this?

Comment: @Kevin not that I'm aware of - I am trying to pass the menu children of the current node in a view.

Comment: Menu Block can read and folllow the active trail of the current uri and make that the starting point for output. https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block - therefore, no Views needed.

Comment: I added a drawing to illustrate what I'm talking about, I don't think menu block solves this issue. Btw, I'm using menu block to render the menu. The question was regarding the 'subpages' section - see drawing above. Let me know if I've misunderstood what menu block can do.

Comment: Can you specify how did you configured the view to filter using menu node children?

Comment: @felipep I wish I new which site this module was used on. I'll try and dig that up so I  can share that with you. I vaguely recall using contextual filters to pass nid of the parent or something to that affect.

Comment: @ymdahi thanks, I already find it out how it works, the parent id is necessary as context filter